# Given (&str, &str), what is an efficient way to look up its entry from a HashMap whose key is (String, String)?

Tags: rust

In Rust, I have a `HashMap` whose key is `(String, String)`. Now I have `(&str, &str)` data. Is there any way to use it as query without making `String`s?

Answer (score 5):

I'm fairly sure this is impossible. But if you can change the `HashMap`, you can get the behavior you're after by using [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html): [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=28571ae8ef16c9354fbf36d70fadbf99)

```rs
// Make the map
let map: HashMap<(Cow<str>, Cow<str>), usize> = [
    ("a", "b"),
    ("c", "d"),
    ("e", "f"),
    ("g", "h"),
    ("i", "j"),
    ("k", "l"),
]
.into_iter()
.enumerate()
.map(|(n, (a, b))| {
    // Create Cows with owned Strings
    let a = Cow::Owned(a.to_string());
    let b = Cow::Owned(b.to_string());
    ((a, b), n)
})
.collect();

// Make some non-'static &strs
let s1 = "e".to_string();
let s2 = "f".to_string();
let c1 = Cow::Borrowed(s1.as_str());
let c2 = Cow::Borrowed(s2.as_str());

// Do a lookup with borrowed Cows
map[&(c1, c2)]
```

If you need to specify the lifetime of the `Cow` inside the `HashMap`, it should be `'static` because all entries are owned. This has a nice side effect of allowing `&'static str` entries as well as `String` entries.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this using `HashMap::raw_entry_mut()` which is currently unstable under the feature `hash_raw_entry` ([issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/56167)). From the comments, it looks like this feature won't be stabilized any time soon, but in case it does, the following code might be useful:

```rust
#![feature(build_hasher_simple_hash_one, hash_raw_entry)]

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::BuildHasher;

fn main() {
    let mut map = vec![
        ((String::from("foo"), String::from("bar")), 1),
        ((String::from("bar"), String::from("baz")), 2),
    ]
    .into_iter()
    .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>();

    for key in [("foo", "foo"), ("bar", "baz")] {
        // We manually compute the hash using the same hasher as the HashMap.
        let hash = map.hasher().hash_one(key);
        // We get the raw entry by passing the hash and a equality function that compares both members of the tuple.
        let raw_entry = map.raw_entry_mut().from_hash(hash, |(a, b)| key == (a, b));
        dbg!(key, raw_entry);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[src/main.rs:19] key = (
    "foo",
    "foo",
)
[src/main.rs:19] raw_entry = RawEntry(
    RawVacantEntryMut { .. },
)
[src/main.rs:19] key = (
    "bar",
    "baz",
)
[src/main.rs:19] raw_entry = RawEntry(
    RawOccupiedEntryMut {
        key: (
            "bar",
            "baz",
        ),
        value: 2,
        ..
    },
)
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=906138181e3b56b0c9260ba3359dab36)

Answer (score 2):

You can define a newtype around `(String, String)` that will implement `Borrow<(&str, &str)>`. The problem is that [`Borrow::borrow()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html#tymethod.borrow) returns a reference, and we cannot construct a reference to `(&str, &str)` because it will be a reference to temporary. If we use [`hashbrown`](https://docs.rs/hashbrown) directly, however, it has the [`Equivalent`](https://docs.rs/hashbrown/latest/hashbrown/trait.Equivalent.html) trait, which is more general than `Borrow` and can fit for your use-case:

```rust
#[derive(Hash)]
struct TwoStrs<'a>(&'a str, &'a str);

impl hashbrown::Equivalent<(String, String)> for TwoStrs<'_> {
    fn equivalent(&self, key: &(String, String)) -> bool {
        self.0 == key.0 && self.1 == key.1
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut map = hashbrown::HashMap::new();
    map.extend([
        (("a".to_owned(), "b".to_owned()), 1),
        (("c".to_owned(), "d".to_owned()), 2),
    ]);
    dbg!(map.get(&TwoStrs("c", "d")));
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, I was able to find what I believe is a sound way to do this with Rust's own `HashMap` and the `Borrow` trait by using arrays instead of tuples. As you are very familiar with this side of Rust, I'd be very appreciative if you could review my answer for soundness. Having said that, this approach or the `Cow`-based one are probably better for actual production use.

Answer (score 1):

I want to preface this answer by saying that I would strongly urge you to go with either the `Cow` approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75830909/501250) or the `hashbrown` approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75833909/501250) instead.  I am providing this answer to show that what you ask *is actually possible* in a way you might not expect, if you are willing to change from tuples to arrays.

---

It's possible to do what you want with a set of newtypes and some unsafe (but sound) casts.

The primary obstacle we run into is the signature of the `HashMap::get` method:

```
pub fn get<Q>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V>
where
    K: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Hash + Eq + ?Sized,
```

And the associated `Borrow` trait:

```
pub trait Borrow<Borrowed>
where
    Borrowed: ?Sized,
{
    fn borrow(&self) -> &Borrowed;
}
```

Working within these constraints, we run into a problem: how can we borrow a `(&str, &str)` from a `(String, String)`?  Note that this doesn't mean producing a `(&str, &str)`, it means producing a `&(&str, &str)`, which means that the tuple and string slices have to live somewhere so we can borrow them.  The answer, sadly, is that we cannot do this.

However, we can take advantage of several [layout guarantees](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html) Rust gives us to produce an alternative solution with the same ownership semantics:

- `[T; N]` has the same layout as `[U; N]` when `T` has the same layout as `U`.
- `&T`, `&mut T`, `*const T`, and `*mut T` all have the same layout.
- A struct tagged `#[repr(transparent)]` and having a single field of type `T` has the same layout as `T`.

Putting this all together, there's a surprising amount we can do!

First, since tuples do not have the same layout guarantees as arrays, we will have to switch from tuples (`(&str, &str)`) to arrays (`[&str; 2]`).  This is not a huge difference, and only changes a bit of syntax we have to use.

The crux of the problem is "how do we borrow the `&str` version from the owned version?"

The simplest way I could get this to work is to represent an owned version as something that we can safely transmute to the borrowed version.  Based on the above rules, we have these two structs:

```
struct Key([*mut str; 2]);

#[repr(transparent)]
struct KeyRef([*const str; 2]);
```

Because of the layout guarantees given above, we can soundly transmute a reference to the first field of `Key` to `&KeyRef`!

We need some extra code to make these types safe to use, of course.  First, let's handle creation and destruction of `Key` values:

```
impl From<[String; 2]> for Key {
    fn from(v: [String; 2]) -> Self {
        let [a, b] = v;

        Self([
            Box::leak(Box::<str>::from(a)),
            Box::leak(Box::<str>::from(b)),
        ])
    }
}

impl Drop for Key {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            drop(Box::from_raw(self.0[0]));
            drop(Box::from_raw(self.0[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

(Side note: A panic in either of these implementations can result in a permanent leak.  I don't solve that here, but the solution isn't very difficult.)

So what we're doing is basically converting two owned strings into two `*mut str`s, which we then have to manage.  The `Drop` implementation takes care of freeing them.

Now let's give this type two helpers, one to view the contained strings and one to take them back out as owned `String`s:

```
impl Key {
    pub fn get(&self) -> &[&str; 2] {
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(&self.0) }
    }
    
    pub fn into_inner(self) -> [String; 2] {
        // Prevent Key's drop code from running after we take the strings.
        let s = std::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(self);

        [
            unsafe { Box::from_raw(s.0[0]) }.into(),
            unsafe { Box::from_raw(s.0[1]) }.into(),
        ]
    }
}
```

The same `get` helper can be provided for `KeyRef`, which will aid in the implementation of `PartialEq` and `Hash` later:

```
impl KeyRef {
    pub fn get(&self) -> &[&str; 2] {
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(&self.0) }
    }
}
```

The next two pieces of the solution are the `Borrow` implementation, and a way to construct a `KeyRef` from a pair of `&str`s:

```
impl Borrow<KeyRef> for Key {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &KeyRef {
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(&self.0) }
    }
}

impl<'a> From<&'a [&'a str; 2]> for &'a KeyRef {
    fn from(v: &'a [&'a str; 2]) -> &'a KeyRef {
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(v) }
    }
}
```

There's a lot of transmuting going on here, but in all cases we are transmuting between references to arrays of the same length where the elements have compatible layouts.  And, because `KeyRef` is `#[repr(transparent)]`, we can transmute a reference to an array with a compatible layout as `KeyRef`'s own array type directly to a `&KeyRef`.

The final pieces needed to use these in a `HashMap` are the equality and hash implementations.

```
impl Hash for Key {
    fn hash<H>(&self, h: &mut H) where H: std::hash::Hasher {
        let [a, b] = self.get();

        a.hash(h);
        b.hash(h);
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Key {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.get() == other.get()
    }
}

impl Eq for Key {}

impl Hash for KeyRef {
    fn hash<H>(&self, h: &mut H) where H: std::hash::Hasher {
        let [a, b] = self.get();
        
        a.hash(h);
        b.hash(h);
    }
}

impl PartialEq for KeyRef {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.get() == other.get()
    }
}

impl Eq for KeyRef {}
```

And finally, we can test the implementation:

```
fn main() {
    let mut map = std::collections::HashMap::new();
    
    map.insert(Key::from(["foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string()]), 42);
    
    assert_eq!(
        Some(&42),
        map.get(<&KeyRef>::from(&["foo", "bar"]))
    );
    
    assert_eq!(
        None,
        map.get(<&KeyRef>::from(&["foo", "baz"]))
    );
}
```

You can see all of this code put together on [the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=323478d16b11398be9dceccb409a2e1e).

This is a bare-bones proof of concept.  You'd probably want to add some other facilities, such as `Clone` and `Debug` implementations on both types (`KeyRef` can also implement `Copy`).

Comment: This is sound, but it means you cannot grow the strings. However, because they're used as keys in a hashmap, you cannot mutate them anyway.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Right, that was my thought as well. If mutating is needed, one can extract them with `.into_inner()` and then reform the `Key`.